# Joining specific days of data to a daily time series (Teradata SQL)

Tags: sql, teradata

I had a hard time summarizing what I am looking to do in the title but the example I have should make sense. I am trying to write a more efficient query in Teradata that will be used in Tableau. I can get it done with the brute strength an ignorance approach but after a while I run out of spool space so I need to make it more efficient.

Let's say I have two tables, a customer table with customer attributes and a daily balance table (it is more complex than that but this is the important part). I want to write a query that returns the daily balance per customer along with other columns that are a specific days balance for that customer regardless of date field in the final table.

Example:

Customer Table

```
CustID | CustState | CustType | ...
001    | NY        | A        | ...
002    | CA        | B        | ...    
003    | NC        | C        | ...
```

Balance Table

```
CustID | Date      | Balance
001    |04/01/2018 | 100
001    |04/02/2018 | 105
001    |04/03/2018 | 110
002    |04/01/2018 | 5000
002    |04/02/2018 | 15000
002    |04/03/2018 | 25
```

Final Query Results

```
CustID | CustState | Date      | Balance | Balance42 | Balance43
001    | NY        |04/01/2018 | 100     | 105       | 110
001    | NY        |04/02/2018 | 105     | 105       | 110
001    | NY        |04/03/2018 | 110     | 105       | 110
002    | CA        |04/01/2018 | 5000    | 1500      | 25
002    | CA        |04/02/2018 | 15000   | 1500      | 25
002    | CA        |04/03/2018 | 25      | 1500      | 25
```

As you can see the first four columns are straight forward, the last two represent the balance from 4/2/2018 and 4/3/2018 respectively. I am currently doing this like the following where I use multiple joins/subqueries to get the specific balances:

```
select a.CustID
  , a.CustState
  , b.Date
  , sum(b.Balance) as Balance
  , c.Balance as Balance42
  , d.Balance as Balance43

from Customer a

inner join Balance b on a.CustID=b.CustID

inner join (
  select aa.CustID
    , sum(bb.Balance) as Balance
  from Customer aa
  inner join Balance bb on aa.CustID=bb.CustID
  where aa.CustType in ('A','B')
    and bb.Date=DATE '2018-04-02
  group by aa.CustID
) c on a.CustID=c.CustID 

inner join (
  select aa.CustID
    , sum(bb.Balance) as Balance
  from Customer aa
  inner join Balance bb on aa.CustID=bb.CustID
  where aa.CustType in ('A','B')
    and bb.Date=DATE '2018-04-03
  group by aa.CustID
) d on a.CustID=c.CustID 

where a.CustType in ('A','B')

group by a.CustID
  , a.CustState
  , b.Date
  , c.Balance
  , d.Balance
```

Is there a way that I can do this with only one join/subquery to be more efficient? I start to run out of spool space when I add too many joins/subqueries but I have a specific business use for why I am trying to get the final results structure.

Comment: In the fourth row, you already have the balance for 4/1, 4/2, and 4/3.  Is there a reason that you are duplicating it in the last two columns?  If not, would eliminating those two options be acceptable or removing the extra rows with duplicate data?

Comment: I am duplicating that data because when I pull the data in Tableau it will allow me to easily compare that balance from those specific dates to the other dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *conditional agregation*, but in your case it's based on a *Windowed Aggregate*:

```
select a.CustID
  , a.CustState
  , b.Date
  , sum(b.Balance) as Balance 

  , max(case when b.Date=DATE '2018-04-02' then sum(b.Balance) end)
    over (partition by a.CustID) as Balance42

  , max(case when b.Date=DATE '2018-04-03' then sum(b.Balance) end)
    over (partition by a.CustID) as Balance43

from Customer a

inner join Balance b on a.CustID=b.CustID

where a.CustType in ('A','B')

group by a.CustID
  , a.CustState
  , b.Date
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much for your help, I knew it had to be something easy I wasn't thinking of and that nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely get what you are trying to do.  But it seems to be you should be able to do it in one statement, using case statements for your last two calculations:

```
select a.CustID
  , a.CustState
  , b.Date
  , sum(b.Balance) as Balance
  , sum (case when b.date = '2018-04-02' then b.balance else null end) as balance42
  , sum (case when b.date = '2018-04-03' then b.balance else null end) as balance 43
from Customer a

inner join Balance b on a.CustID=b.CustID
```

Comment: When I do that it does not populate the balance from 4/2 for every date, only when date equals 4/2. Is there a way to have that balance on every row regardless of the date field?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative query without OLAP (it only works if Customer.CustID is PK)

```
with x as (
  select a.CustID
    , a.CustState
    , b.Date
    , sum(b.Balance) as Balance 
  from Customer a
  inner join Balance b on a.CustID=b.CustID
  where a.CustType in ('A','B')
  group by a.CustID
    , a.CustState
    , b.Date
)
select x.CustID
    , x.CustState
    , x.Date
    , x.Balance
    , d1.Balance as Balance42
    , d2.Balance as Balance43
from x
inner join x d1 when d1.CustID = x.CustID and d1.Date=DATE '2018-04-02'
inner join x d2 when d2.CustID = x.CustID and d2.Date=DATE '2018-04-03'
```